# How to write SQL query for returning column1 value based on value from another column2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have below data column1 representing percentage and column2 some random values , Need some inputs how to build a sql query such that we need percentage value based on criteria from column 2 values ,For example

1. if user input is 600 , my query  should return 20% as it falls under 599<600<=605
2. if user input is 599 then my query  should return 19 %

| percentage | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 19% | 599 |
| 20% | 605 |

Comment: Show us your query attempt. (I know how to do it, but I don't know the SQL Server way to handle query user input.)

Comment: we can hardcode the input

Answer (score 4):

```
Select TOP 1 Percentage from Table_Name where Value >= Column2_Input_Values 
order by Value
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use `LEAD` function, in order to build the from/to boundaries. If your query is atomic, the other answer is far way easier.

```
with your_data as (
  select 19 as percentage, 599 as value union all
  select 20 as percentage, 605 as value
)
select percentage, value as fromValue,
  isnull(lead(value) over (partition by (select null) order by value asc), 99999) as toValue
from your_data
```

[image: output]

Example

```
declare @val int = 600

;with your_data as (
  select 19 as percentage, 599 as value union all
  select 20 as percentage, 605 as value
),
bound as (
  select percentage, value as fromValue,
    isnull(lead(value) over (partition by (select null) order by value asc), 99999) as toValue
  from your_data
)
select percentage
from bound
where fromValue <= @val 
  and toValue > @val
```

[image: output]